# _tkinter.TclError: Item 1 not found

Tags: python-3.x, database, tkinter

for i in range(len(data)):
treeview.insert(data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], text = data[i][4])
output:
line 1368, in insert
"-id", iid, *opts)
_tkinter.TclError: Item 1 not found

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a [tour] and lean how to [ask]. Simply dumping an error without further explanation, a question or a [mre] will not get you any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are trying to insert some data into the `Treeview` widget in tkinter. To do that you should use the following

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    name_of_treeview.insert('', 'end', values = (a, b, c,...)
# a, b, c are values
```

Comment: you forgot a bracket at the end of the second line

Comment: @CoolCloud is it mine or yash's?

Comment: yours `name_of_treeview.insert('', 'end', values = (a, b, c,...)` here

Comment: thanks  and next time i'll see to it --> Next time, you ask a question please be more elaborate@PranavKrishna.S

Comment: Welcome and thanks to you for accepting this as the best answer! By the way @CoolCloud sorry for missing that bracket

Comment: Welcome to SO :D

Comment: Just a typo... By the way not new to SO :)